# Несколько Action в Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Возможно ли в `Html.BeginForm` сделать несколько `Action` на разных кнопках?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Get, new { @Class = "form-inline" }))
{
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", Id = "Name" })
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="button1" value="SomeValue" class="btn btn-primary"  />
      <input type="submit" name="button2" value="SomeValue" class="btn btn-primary" />
   </div>
}
```

Как нужно преобразовать код, чтобы кнопки `button1` и `button2` вызывали разные `Action` и передавали модель?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте атрибут `formaction` тэга `input`.

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="SomeValue" class="btn btn-primary"
  formaction="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" />
```

Comment: При добавлении `Html.Action` внутрь `Html.BeginForm` приложение почему-то не запускается

Comment: @Sv__t, потому что нужно не `Html.Action`, а какой-нибудь `Url.Action`

Comment: Пардон, не тот хелпер.

Comment: в IE9 не поддерживается, если этому важно вдруг кому.